# How to remove break tags from outside the paragraph

Tags: php, html

I want to remove all the `<br>` tags outside the `<p></p>`. But the breaks inside the `<p></p>` should not be hurt. How can i achieve this in php. Below is an example.

```
$html = "<br> <p> This is the Firs para <br> 
        This is a line after the first break <br>
        This is the line after the 2nd break <br>
        Here the first para ends </p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p> This is the 2nd para <br> 
        This is a line after the first break in 2nd para <br>
        This is the line after the 2nd break <br>
        Here the 2nd para ends </p>"
```

I want the result to be as below

```
$html = "<p> This is the Firs para <br> 
        This is a line after the first break <br>
        This is the line after the 2nd break <br>
        Here the first para ends </p>
        <p> This is the 2nd para <br> 
        This is a line after the first break in 2nd para <br>
        This is the line after the 2nd break <br>
        Here the 2nd para ends </p>"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will help you.

```
$out = preg_replace("(<p(?:\s+\w+(?:=\w+|\"[^\"]+\"|'[^']+')?)*>.*?</p>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)"
."|<br>)is", "", $html);

echo $out;
```

Comment: This worked though i had to make a small change. I had to put single quotes inside the regex and remove all the double quotes. Thanks @Arturs

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$text = '<br> <p> This is the Firs para <br> 
        This is a line after the first break <br>
        This is the line after the 2nd break <br>
        Here the first para ends </p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p> This is the 2nd para <br> 
        This is a line after the first break in 2nd para <br>
        This is the line after the 2nd break <br>
        Here the 2nd para ends </p>';

$pattern = '/(<br>[\s\r\n]*<p>|<\/p>[\s\r\n]*<br>)/';
$replacewith = '<p>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacewith, $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

below is solution may be it can help you.

```
$html = "";
$html .="<p><br>This is the Firs para <br> 
        This is a line after the first break <br>
        This is the line after the 2nd break <br>
        Here the first para ends </p>";

        $html .= "<p><br> This is the 2nd para <br> 
        This is a line after the first break in 2nd para <br>
        This is the line after the 2nd break <br>
        Here the 2nd para ends </p>";

echo $html;
```